# How do I find the gasPrice of a confirmed transaction with ethers js?

Tags: gas-price, ethers.js

How do I find the gas price of a confirmed transaction with ethers js?

Answer (score 4):

[getTransactionReceipt](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider-getTransactionReceipt)

> gasUsed: { BigNumber: "443560" },

and the total cost of the transaction

```
  getTxCost = async (txHash) => {
        let receipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
        return receipt.effectiveGasPrice.mul(receipt.gasUsed);
      };
```

Comment: To get the price in USD, do you take this output and multiply it by the price of ETH in USD? Also the units return from the function is in wei and not gwei right

Answer (score 1):

`provider.getTransaction([transactionHash])`